# POSTGRESQL client side encoding vs server side encoding

Tags: postgresql, performance, encoding, character-encoding

I'm using postgresql 9.6. I migrated an oracle system from oracle to postgresql. The data that is saved in the database is saved in Hebrew. Therefore, in order to see it I need to change the character set from default to ISO_8859_8.  Now I can drop the database and create a new one with different encoding and I can also set the different encoding on the client side (psql). I want to understand what is better in point of view of performance.

Thanks, Mariel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app uses or supports UTF-8, use UTF-8 in the database. That should generally be the default, so if the DB is already UTF-8, consider leaving it that way.

If the app only supports ISO-8859-8, you may wish to restrict the DB to ISO-8859-8 to prevent insertion of data by things other than the app that will then prevent the app reading the data. But that's about the only reason not to use utf-8.

Efficiency is not really a concern, it just doesn't make much difference in practice. Sorts can be a bit slower on utf-8 but even then, not much.

The main thing to do there is use `COLLATE "C` indexes, operators, etc, when you don't care about lexical sorting and you only want byte-value sorting. This is useful whether the DB is ISO-8859-8, UTF-8, or anything else.

Comment: The app connects via psql from the server (it runs some procedures that analyze the data and create excels..) So I can set the encoding on both sides, on which side it is better ? The db is sql_asci default.. somethink like that.

Comment: If it's just invoking `psql` then I'd use utf-8 in the DB, and set `client_encoding` to `ISO-88590-8`, in the anticipation that I might need wider encodings later. But there's nothing wrong with just making the DB `ISO-8859-8` if you know for sure you won't need to store text outside that space.

**Do not use `SQL_ASCII`**. You definitely need to fix that, which will require a dump and reload.

Comment: I had mistake. I checked again and my db encoding is set to utf8, collate - en_us.UTF-8,Ctype=en_US.UTF8. So in that case, I should just set the client_encoding to ISO-88590-8? Does it have any impact on the database performance ?

Comment: It could have a small CPU cost if you're doing lots of bulk text transfer, but it's usually negligible. It's what I'd recommend.

Comment: I tried to set client_encdoing to ISO-88590-8 but i got error psql: FATAL: invalid value for parameter “client_encoding”: “ ISO-88590-8”

Comment: `ISO-8859-8` , typo above

Comment: Yeah it worked, I will perform some checks. thank you very much !

Comment: For some unclear reason, the client_encoding set to ISO_8859_8 and the server_encoding set to utf8 and still I dont see hebrew letters.

Comment: when I use pgAdmin I see the hebrew characters but with psql I see just gibbrish.

Comment: @Mariel Are you on Windows? If so, you'll need to `chcp 65001` before starting `psql` so you get a Unicode capable terminal. Unless your Windows is set to use ANSI code page ISO-8859-8. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#AEN100891 "Notes for Windows users"

Comment: I created html pages from the data in the tables and I realize that in my html files that encoding was set to unicde. changing it to UTF8 solved my issue. Thank you both very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you only use Latin-8 on the client side, it is probably most efficient to use the same encoding for the database, since no conversion is necessary.

If there is a chance that you need to store other characters too, use UTF-8.

Comment: Ahm, I want to make sure before I do any changes. I have an oracle database with  NLS_CHARACTERSET set to  IW8ISO8859P8. I bring data from that oracle database to my postgresql. After that I create from that data excel files. The data stored in hebrew therefore I thought that I need to change the character set of the client/server to ISO_8859_8. So, I should change the encoding on both sides ? or stay with utf8 ? (I'm not sure it supports hebrew..)

Comment: You can use wither encoding for the PostgreSQL database, and for the client you have to use the encoding that the application (Excel) expects.

Comment: I set the psql encoding to ISO_8859_8 but the text seems like gebbrish. The app connets to the database through psql.

Comment: when I use pgAdmin I see the hebrew characters but with psql I see just gibbrish.

Comment: The app connects via *psql* ? Not a database driver like ODBC, nPGSQL, PgJDBC, etc? But the actual `psql` command line client? What a bizarre and horrid way for the app to communicate with the database :(

Comment: If you see gibberish when you use `ISO_8859_8`, it is probably your terminal that expects some other encoding (probably UTF-8).

Comment: I created html pages from the data in the tables and I realize that in my html files that encoding was set to unicde. changing it to UTF8 solved my issue. Thank you both very much!